# LED floodlight blink on/off once when turned on

Tags: led

We just bought new LED bulbs to replace the old (non-LED) bulbs in our outdoor floodlights. Old bulb=120W; LED=15W. The LEDs are rated for use outside, and are Edison style. The problem is: when we turn the light switch on, the bulbs give a single, very fast (~300-500ms) "on" blink and then turn off. They never turn back on. Any thoughts on trouble shooting would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do they blink every time you turn the switch on, or did they only blink once ever and then permanently stop working?

Comment: What kind of switch(es) do you have? Simple toggle/rocker? "Smart"? Dimmer? Timer? Motion sensor?

Comment: They blink on and off ever time I turn on the switch.

Comment: The switch is just a standard toggle on/off. We do have a motion sensor, though.

Answer (score 2):

They might be cheapo's.  But most likely, there is a "smart or powered switch" somewhere in the works.  Motion sensor, day/night sensor, who knows what?

Whatever it is, it's not playing well with the LED's.

The surest way to test this is to put 1 incandescent back.  If it suddenly behaves properly now, then an obsolete electronic thing is at fault.

You can either modernize it (note *many* such things require neutral!), or make *at least one bulb* a "better" grade of LED which is designed to play nice with these types of obsolete devices. Often they are marketed as "dimmable".